# Filter for JSF table

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I would like to add filter for JSF table and limit the values based on filter value.

```
<h:inputText id="search" value="#{accounts.searchString}"></h:inputText>

<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{accounts.search()}">
    <f:ajax execute="search" render="output"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

I suppose that the best way will be to add the filter value into the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ?
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/eEeTWEqK

How I can implement this for the code into the link?

PS. I modified the code this way:

```
<div class="div_input_style">
    <h:inputText id="search" class="input_style" value="#{accounts.searchString}"></h:inputText>

    <h:commandButton class="theSpan" value="Search by title">
        <f:ajax execute="search" render="output"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
</div>
```

```
public List<AccountsObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException
    {
        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

        SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT "
            + " WHERE ? IS NULL OR ? IN (USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)"
            + " ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ? ";

        String sql = String.format(SqlStatement, sortField, sortDirection);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<AccountsObj> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, searchString);
            ps.setString(2, searchString);
            ps.setInt(3, firstRow);
            ps.setInt(4, rowCount);

            resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            resultList = ProcessorArrayList(resultSet);

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;

        }
        finally
        {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: I think the best way is the use of [Primefaces Datatable filtering builtin feature](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml), this way you won't need to touch SQL completely.

Comment: Well, in my case prefer to use core JSF. I have a lot of custom things. Can you give a hand here, please?

Comment: This question is too broad. Please, try to implement it yourself and, if any concrete problem appears, ask it here. As a recommendation, do NOT place search arguments in the raw query directly, as it makes SQL injection possible. Use query parameters instead.

Comment: SQL injection is not a problem. This is internal system and I also use prepared statements. Look at the code I use lazy pagination. Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Try asking a concrete question and not chameleonize it into a completely different question as you progresses. Your question in its current form is confusing. It contradicts the answer, so I deleted it. Also, a lot of people don't read code posted behind a link. Just post problematic code in MCVE flavor. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info If you can't post a MCVE but only 100+ lines of spaghetti code, then you have a different problem (which can be solved by learning to write code instead of to copypaste code).